# How to make an "global parser rule"?

Tags: antlr4

I'm building a grammar for parsing Quake III shaders with ANTLR4.

Here's an exemple of a shader:

```
textures/liquids/lava-example
{
    deformVertexes wave sin 0 3 0 0.1
    q3map_tessSize 64
    surfaceparm lava
    qer_editorimage textures/common/lava.tga
    {
        map textures/common/lava.tga
    }
}
```

As you can see, the structure is:

```
shadername
{
    directive
    directive
    //....
    {
        directive
        //...
    }
}
```

**My question**

As you can see, a directive is composed by a key and some parameters. The keys and the parameters are known (more than 100 keys possible). I wonder how to set a global rule for a directive (key + parameters) and specify all of them beside of it. Moreover, if I can separate all of them in different files for keeping clean grammars, it is better.

**What I have for now**

```
parser grammar ShaderParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=ShaderLexer; 
}

shaderlist
    : shader+
    ;

shader
    : shadername LBracket directive* stage* RBracket
    ;

shadername
    : Path CompileTime?
    ;

stage
    : LBracket directive* RBracket
    ;

directive
    : key parameter?
    | key DQuote parameter DQuote
    | key SQuote parameter SQuote
    ;

key
    : Word
    ;

parameter
    : Word 
    | Integer 
    | Double
    | Path 
    ;
```

The directive, key and parameter (a single one for testing) rules were just for getting the main grammar.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The grammar seems to need newlines as statement separators. You should add them at the end of each directive. Also the parameters you can match with your grammar will be one at most.

```
shader
    : shadername NEWLINE
      LBracket NEWLINE
      directive* 
      stage* 
      RBracket NEWLINE? 
      EOF
    ;

shadername
    : Path CompileTime?
    ;

stage
    : LBracket NEWLINE
        directive* 
      RBracket NEWLINE
    ;

directive
    : key mayBeQuotedParameter* NEWLINE
    ;

mayBeQuotedParameter   
    : parameter?
    | DQuote parameter DQuote
    | SQuote parameter SQuote        
    ;

key
    : Word
    ;

parameter
    : Word 
    | Integer 
    | Double
    | Path 
    ;
```